# SQS rate limiting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I would like to use the AWS SDK for JavaScript to build a publicly serverless application. Aside from serving static content, I need it to send messages to SQS.

Now, obviously I don't want an attacker to be able to submit a few million of these messages in a few seconds. How can I implement this in reasonably secure way, ideally with rate limiting by client?